Failed to Deploy Apex classes with sfdx mdapi
In my nodejs code, I created a function to deploy all apex classes i have in a folder within the project. that's the part of the code responsible for that :
function deployAllApexClasses(orgAlias, callback) {
  const command = `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d "${deploymentFolderPath}" -u ${orgAlias} -w -1 --json`;

  exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log('Command output:', stdout);
    if (error) {
      console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
      console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
      callback({
        error: 'Failed to deploy Apex classes',
        details: stderr,
        command
      });
      return;
    }

    try {
      const result = JSON.parse(stdout);
      if (result.status === 0) {
        callback(null, { message: 'Apex classes deployed successfully.', details: result.result });
      } else {
        console.error(`Failed to deploy Apex classes: ${result.message}`);
        callback({
          error: 'Failed to deploy Apex classes',
          details: result.message,
          command
        });
      }
    } catch (parseError) {
      console.error(`Error parsing output: ${parseError}`);
      console.error(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
      callback({
        error: 'Failed to deploy Apex classes',
        details: `Parse error: ${parseError.message}`,
        stdout,
        command
      });
    }
  });
}

// Route to deploy all Apex classes from predefined folder based on org alias provided
app.get('/deployAllApexClasses', (req, res) => {
  const { orgAlias } = req.query;
  if (!orgAlias) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Org alias is required' });
  }

  deployAllApexClasses(orgAlias, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      return res.status(500).json(error);
    }
    res.json(result);
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

The deploymentFolderPath is also defined in the beginning of the code
when i start the server and test the function with this command after replacing orgAlias with the one of my actual org : "http://localhost:3001/deployAllApexClasses?orgAlias=orgAlias"
i get that the deployment is successfull but no apex classes were deployed :



Is there a "deployment" in the target environment in Setup -> Deployment status? Was it successful? How much components are in it?

yes, the folder is already cretaed. the response indicates that the deployment is successful but it also indicates that no components were deployed. I have 7 apex classes to deploy

I would assume there is something wrong with path to the metadata. My suggestion would be to use '-s' argument to check if it works or recheck if deploymentFolderPath is correct
